# PHP make fails with error: Undefined symbols _XpmLibraryVersion

Tags: php, compiler-errors, gd, osx-mavericks

I am trying to compile PHP myself on Mac OS X Mavericks.

Here is the configure command:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/local/php --with-config-file-path=/opt/local/php/conf 
--with-apxs2=/opt/local/apache/bin/apxs --with-mysql=/opt/local/mysql 
--with-mysql-sock=/tmp --with-libedit --with-pcre-dir=/opt/local 
--enable-bcmath --enable-mbstring --enable-sockets --enable-zip --with-bz2 
--with-curl --with-jpeg-dir=/opt/local --with-png-dir=/opt/local 
--with-freetype-dir=/opt/local --with-gd=/opt/local
```

When I try to d `sudo make`, I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "_XpmLibraryVersion", referenced from:
   _zm_info_gd in gd.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**PHP version is 5.5.5** and **libgd** was compiled with this config:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/local --with-png=/opt/local --with-jpeg=/opt/local 
--with-tiff=/opt/local --with-freetype=/opt/local
```

Without the `--with-gd` flag, PHP compiles just fine.

What does this error mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass --with-xpm-dir=no to configure which should disable xpm support, if that doesn't resolve it try installing the [X11 Update](http://support.apple.com/downloads/X11_for_Mac_OS_X_1_0) for Mac OS X. And, you should probably recompile [libgd](http://libgd.bitbucket.org) after installing that update (to include libXpm)

Comment: Thanks for reply! I tried both options, but they didn't help, still the same problem.

Comment: Interesting. You can try recompiling http://libgd.bitbucket.org/ libgd after installing X11 (to include libXpm), but otherwise I'm baffled.

Comment: Finally! You are the man! Problem solved. Man i love you, i spend almost half a day with this problem and i didn't think that i can just use libXpm from XQuartz. So i recompiled GD with xpm and php with xpm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This options help me on Debian:

```
--with-gd=/usr/ --with-xpm-dir=/usr/ '--with-libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'
```